# Firebase RecyclerView is not showing any data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my firebase recycler view data is not showing i've tried sevral way but can't find my answer please help
my firebase recycler view data is not showing i've tried sevral way but can't find my answer please help
my firebase recycler view data is not showing i've tried sevral way but can't find my answer please help
my firebase recycler view data is not showing i've tried sevral way but can't find my answer please help

Show_Activity.java

```
public class Show_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView   recyclerView;
    private FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference root = db.getReference().child("Matches");
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Model> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        list = new ArrayList<>();

        root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Model model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Model.class);
                    list.add( new Model(model.matchname,model.bettingamt));
                    Log.i("THE_CURRENT_USER:::", model.toString());
                }
                LinearLayoutManager im = new LinearLayoutManager((Show_Activity.this));
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(im);
                adapter = new MyAdapter(list);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Model> mList;
    Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context , ArrayList<Model> mList){    
        this.mList = mList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Model> list) {

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.game , parent ,false);

return new MyViewHolder(v);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Model model = mList.get(position);
        holder.matchname.setText(model.getMatchname());
        holder.bettingamount.setText(model.getBettingamt());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }
    public static  class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView matchname , bettingamount;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            matchname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.matchname);
            bettingamount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bettingamt);
        }
    }
}
```

Model.java

```
public class Model {
    public String getMatchname() {
        return matchname;
    }

    public void setMatchname(String matchname) {
        this.matchname = matchname;
    }

    public String getBettingamt() {
        return bettingamt;
    }

    public void setBettingamt(String bettingamt) {
        this.bettingamt = bettingamt;
    }

    public Model(String matchname, String bettingamt) {
        this.matchname = matchname;
        this.bettingamt = bettingamt;
    }

    String matchname , bettingamt;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See at youre MyAdapter constructors:

```
public MyAdapter(Context context , ArrayList<Model> mList){

        this.mList = mList;
        this.context = context;
    }

public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Model> list) {

    }
```

and see what you do after data ready:

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(list);
```

So, you must call `adapter = new MyAdapter(Show_Activity.this, list);`

Comment: so what should i do now ?  should i edit  adapter = new MyAdapter(list); to adapter = new MyAdapter(mList); ?

Comment: new MyAdapter(this, list)

Comment: error: incompatible types: <anonymous ValueEventListener> cannot be converted to Context
                adapter = new MyAdapter(this, mList);
                                        ^    im getting this error

Comment: Use Show_Activity.this.

Comment: Thanks bro !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! i was finding the solution from past 1 week . finally got my answer love you bro ♥♥♥♥

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add a default constructor for your model class

```
public Model(){}
```

And change `adapter = new MyAdapter(list);` to `adapter = new MyAdapter(this,list);`